# iOS Webview Keyboard Crash

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, intel-xdk, appframework

I am developing an app using Intel's XDK App Framework. When building my app for iOS I noticed that the keyboard can crash the app under certain circumstances. I was able to create a demo app with just 3 inputs, that can easily reproduce the crash. After communicating with Intel, I am unsure whether it is an issue with their code, or something wrong with the webview in which my app is embedded.

To reproduce the crash, I created a blank app with the following html in the page.

```
<input type="text">
<input type="time"></input>
<select>
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
  <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

To then trigger the crash, I follow these steps.

1. Tap the text input and enter some text
2. Start repeatedly tapping the time input, or the select input
3. If the text input highlights it's text, tap back into the text input to get a cursor again and restart. If the text input keyboard closes, start again

The strange thing is that when focusing the time input or the select list, the iOS keyboard remains open. It is only while both the keyboard and another input are open that the app crashes. I have tested on safari on iOS and this doesn't happen.

Has anyone had a similar experience with the webview? Is anyone able to test this on a phonegap/cordova app?

**UPDATE**

This is a problem with iOS UIWebView. I have been able to reproduce the crash on an Intel XDK build with no JavaScript, and on a PhoneGap build with no JavaScript. You don't even need to type in the text box as I first suspected, just tap between the inputs quickly. I have also only been able to reproduce this on an iPad 2, I could not trigger the crash on an iPad Air.

I have logged a bug with Apple, and will post an answer if they are able to provide a fix

**UPDATE**

Received the following reply from apple.

> Engineering has determined that your bug report (19218381) is a
>   duplicate of another issue (18487570) and will be closed.

There doesn't seem to be a way to view the other issue though so I cannot find out if it was resolved or has any workarounds. Thanks Apple! I tried looking up the bug on [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=18487570) but just found another ticket with the same issue, that was also closed as a duplicate.

Comment: any update on the bug from apple, or workarounds?

Comment: I got the following reply "Engineering has determined that your bug report (19218381) is a duplicate of another issue (18487570) and will be closed.". There seems to be no way for me to view the other issue though, so I've pretty much given up

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can post your full app somewhere?  Are you using the XDK cloud build system, or cordova cli to build?  What version of iOS is this happening on?  Someone reported something similar, but it was their CSS causing the crash (as odd as it sounds)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this was happening on iOS 8.1.1 on an iPad 2. The project has no CSS, and the html above is pretty much the entire source, just wrapped in html/body tags. I have done more testing and I think the problem lies with Apple now (see my update above).